# Adding steps after pushing images in GCP Cloud Container Builder

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry, google-cloud-platform

I’m using "Google Cloud Container Builder" to build and deploy my containers, but I need to do my build steps, then push my images, the do my deploy steps.

As far as I know, the way to push images is by adding

```
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/image1'
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/image2'
```

to the bottom of the `cloudbuild.yaml` file, but what if I need to do steps after I’ve pushed the images?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At this time, there is no way to take additional steps as part of that build process once the images have been pushed. If you want to take additional steps after a successful push, you have a few options:

1. Use a build step to push your images instead; Container Builder will treat that like any other step. The supported [docker build step](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/docker) could be used in this way to do a `docker push...` using the same credentials that your build uses. Note that if you go this route, you would (presumably) omit the `images` field from your cloudbuild.yaml (unless there are other images you want pushed).
2. The other possibility is to have two separate builds. You could listen for GCR push notifications on Cloud Pub Sub; when the first build pushes the expected images, use that as a trigger to launch the second build.

Does one of these solutions give you what you need?

(Disclosure: I'm a Google Engineer who works on Container Builder.)

Comment: Thankyou David, this was very helpful! I will go with the first approach.

Comment: Hi Simon, I slightly misspoke... you need not use the gcloud build step but can in fact directly use the [docker build step](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/docker) to do this. We put credentials into place such that the raw docker build step can push to GCR. I've edited my answer above to reflect this, and I'm going to update the README documentation to reflect this now...

Comment: Documentation for the [docker build step](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/docker) now includes a brief explanation of credentials.

Comment: I have tried the first approach but it doesn't seem to be working.

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'args: ['docker', '--', 'push',     'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/node-frontend']

results in ERROR: (gcloud.docker) Docker is not installed.

Comment: I've changed from the **gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud** image to **gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker** and can now push, thank you once again David.

Comment: Having no out of the box notification functionality is incredibly short sighted. Its like typical Google fashion, you guys do all the really complicated stuff. Then ignore simple product details that make the product nearly useless. Who wants a CI system that doesn't have notification @DavidBendory

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @MatthewKanwisher. You'll notice that we call this product "Container Builder", not "CI System." It's intended to be used as a builder, just one tool in the CI toolbox. That said, we are aware of the need for comprehensive CI and are exploring possibilities.